# Which automorphisms of a set are Gyroautomorphisms

Tags: gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

From the definition of [Gyrogroups](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyrovector_space), it seems clear that, when we get the gyroautomorphism, the gyrogroup is somehow determined, or vice-versa.

My question is how do we determine which automorphisms of a set are gyroautomorphisms. Like trivial automorphism is always gyro, but as far as the papers I have seen, there seems no way to tell which of the automorphisms of the set are gyro. The gyration identity give link between the binary operations, it's inverse and the gyroautomorphism, but still then the question shifts as to which binary operations are gyro?

In addition, suppose I define an arbitrary automorphism, is there any way to determine uniquely the binary operation for gyration identity to hold. Any hints? Thanks beforehand.